# Type 'number[]' has no properties in common with type 'XrangePointOptionsObject' in Angular8 using Highcharts

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to add a Heatmap using highcharts in Angular8 however the typescript shows the following error

> "Type 'number[]' has no properties in common with type
>   'XrangePointOptionsObject'."

So i know that the error comes from the part series.data, when i comment out the data arrays the page loads with empty fields on the heatmap. I have developed similar charts using javascript before but this is the first time i am using typescript to create a chart. The Highchart options for this heatmap are basically from here - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_highcharts/angular_highcharts_heat_map.htm

This is the .ts file for the heatmap :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as highchartsHeatmap from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';
import HeatmapModule from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';
HeatmapModule(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heatmap',
  template: '<div id="container"style="height: 400px; min-width: 380px"></div>',
})

export class HeatMapComponent implements OnInit {

  chartObject: Highcharts.Chart = null;
  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chartObject = Highcharts.chart(

      {
        chart: {
          renderTo:"container",
          type: 'heatmap',
          marginTop: 40,
          marginBottom: 80
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
        },
        xAxis: {
          categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas',
            'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
        },
        yAxis: {
          categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
          title: null
        },
        colorAxis: {
          min: 0,
          minColor: '#FFFFFF',
          maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        },
        legend: {
          align: 'right',
          layout: 'vertical',
          margin: 0,
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          y: 25,
          symbolHeight: 280
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
            return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] +
              '</b> sold <br><b>' +
              this.point.value +
              '</b> items on <br><b>' +
              this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
          }
        },
        series: [{
          name: 'sales per employee',
          borderwidth: 1,
          data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67],
          [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48],
          [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52],
          [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16],
          [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115],
          [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120],
          [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96],
          [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30],
          [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84],
          [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],

          datalabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000'
          }
        }]

      }



    );
  }

}
```

What is the correct way to insert chart options using typescript for creating a chart and avoiding similar errors?
Best regards!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to Define the **type** per series.
[image]

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line

Comment: This is the best answer. :)

Comment: appreciate!!!!!!

Answer (score 7):

in the attribute "series", you need to add the type like this :

```
series: [
        {type: undefined,
        name: 'name I',
        data:[1,2,3]},
       {type: undefined,
        name: 'name II',
        data:[4,5,6]}],
```

Comment: Setting series.type to `undefined` is more like a hack than a proper solution, I would strongly recommend to set a correct `series.type` instead.

Comment: my answer is very correct especially for people who do not know the type of data to use.
thank you for helping people and answering their questions
rather to run behind these little details

Comment: I wish this answer wasn't downvoted, then I wouldn't have overlooked it. This could have saved me a couple of hours of work. - Works fine now, thanks to your hack. - The real issue is probably a mistake in the `highcharts.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 5):

So i managed to fix the error myself. In case anyone is having the same error use the following code :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HeatmapModule from 'highcharts/modules/heatmap';
HeatmapModule(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heatmap',
  template: '<div id="heatmap-object"style="height: 400px; min-width: 380px"></div>',
})

export class HeatMapComponent implements OnInit {


  HeatmapObject: Highcharts.Chart = null;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let options = this.HeatmapOptions();
    this.HeatmapObject = Highcharts.chart(options);
  }

  HeatmapOptions(): Highcharts.Options {

    let options: Highcharts.Options = {

      chart: {
        renderTo: 'heatmap-object',
        marginTop: 40,
        marginBottom: 80,
        plotBorderWidth: 1
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Sales per employee per weekday'
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Alexander', 'Marie', 'Maximilian', 'Sophia', 'Lukas', 'Maria', 'Leon', 'Anna', 'Tim', 'Laura']
      },
      yAxis: {
        categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'],
        title: null
      },
      colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#FFFFFF',
        maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
      },
      legend: {
        align: 'right',
        layout: 'vertical',
        margin: 0,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        symbolHeight: 280
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
          return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
            this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
        }
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'heatmap',
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [[0, 0, 10], [0, 1, 19], [0, 2, 8], [0, 3, 24], [0, 4, 67], [1, 0, 92], [1, 1, 58], [1, 2, 78], [1, 3, 117], [1, 4, 48], [2, 0, 35], [2, 1, 15], [2, 2, 123], [2, 3, 64], [2, 4, 52], [3, 0, 72], [3, 1, 132], [3, 2, 114], [3, 3, 19], [3, 4, 16], [4, 0, 38], [4, 1, 5], [4, 2, 8], [4, 3, 117], [4, 4, 115], [5, 0, 88], [5, 1, 32], [5, 2, 12], [5, 3, 6], [5, 4, 120], [6, 0, 13], [6, 1, 44], [6, 2, 88], [6, 3, 98], [6, 4, 96], [7, 0, 31], [7, 1, 1], [7, 2, 82], [7, 3, 32], [7, 4, 30], [8, 0, 85], [8, 1, 97], [8, 2, 123], [8, 3, 64], [8, 4, 84], [9, 0, 47], [9, 1, 114], [9, 2, 31], [9, 3, 48], [9, 4, 91]],
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          color: '#000000'
        }
      }]

    }

    return options;
  }

}
```

Comment: It was not working because you need to specify a type for each series, to let TypeScript know what should be the correct type (as you did).

Comment: @spstrademark it's so friendly of you to just drop 3 pages of code, and to let us search for your changes.

Comment: Hello, i apologize for the difficulty. In on the changes are : "  ngOnInit() {
    let options = this.HeatmapOptions();
    this.HeatmapObject = Highcharts.chart(options);
  } " and "   HeatmapOptions(): Highcharts.Options {

    let options: Highcharts.Options = {
 // some options
 }
 return options;
 } "

Comment: As @MateuszKornecki mentioned, the crux is in `type` property of a series object.

Comment: @spstrademark, you should accept answer of **Aswin KV**. (click on tick between vote up/down arrows. It's nice to reward users for there effort)

Answer (score 1):

Just specify `series.type` in series object.

These are the series options highchart provides.

Highcharts supports a long list of different chart types like line , spline , area , areaspline , column , bar , pie , scatter , gauge , arearange , areasplinerange and columnrange.

```
 series: [
  {
     name: 'Tokyo',
     type:'column',
     data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2,26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
  },
  {
     name: 'New York',
     type:'column',
     data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8,24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
  },
  {
     name: 'Berlin',
     type:'column',
     data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
  },
  {
     name: 'London',
     type:'column',
     data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `type` property in the object of data series array.

For Example,

```
series: [{
      type: 'column', // this is the solution
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    },
    {
      type: 'column', // this is the solution
      name: 'New York',
      data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]
    }]
```